# PHP/MySQL: How to save or insert the selected radio buttons in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, radio-button, save

I have a table having n rows. Each row has a name [came from an Excel file] and 2 sets of radio buttons. How should I save or insert the selected radio buttons in a database?

The structure of my database is: id, name, vote_for_mayor, vote_for_vmayor

Here's my php code.

```
echo '<form name="electionForm" action="submit.php" method="post" onreset="updateButCount(event);">
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

<table id="election" onclick="updateButCount(event);">
list($cols,) = $xlsx->dimension();
$var=0;
$var1=0;
foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $k => $r) {
    $var++;
    $var1++;
    <tr>
        <td>'.$k.'</td>
        <td>'.( (isset($r[0])) ? $r[0] : '&nbsp;' ).'</td>  //names
        <td><input type = "Radio" Name ="vote'.$var.'" value= "pacada"></td>
        <td><input type = "Radio" Name ="vote'.$var.'" value= "toledo"></td>
        <td><input type = "Radio" Name ="vote1'.$var1.'" value= "apostol"></td>
        <td><input type = "Radio" Name ="vote1'.$var1.'" value= "abdul"></td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
</form>';
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html

Comment: I'm using enum for the votes. However, I don't know how to call the name for the radio buttons in order to insert the selected radio buttons. $query = "INSERT INTO votes (`id`,`name`,`vote_for_mayor`,`vote_for_vmayor`) VALUES ('$k','$r','$vote(for mayor)', '$vote(for vmayor)') ";.

Comment: Maybe this sheds some light? http://www.phpforkids.com/php/php-forms-get-post-checkbox-radio-data.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the HTML to:

```
    <td><input type = "Radio" Name ="vote['.$var.']" value= "pacada"></td>
    <td><input type = "Radio" Name ="vote['.$var.']" value= "toledo"></td>
    <td><input type = "Radio" Name ="vote1['.$var.']" value= "apostol"></td>
    <td><input type = "Radio" Name ="vote1['.$var.']" value= "abdul"></td>
```

Then when processing the form, the variables `$_POST['vote']` and `$_POST['vote1']` will be arrays containing the value of the radio button on each row. You can loop through them and insert them into the database.

Comment: Thank you... I will try your suggestion.

Comment: The votes are now in an array but I'm not really sure how to do the loop that you've mentioned. I tried this but it's not working foreach($vote as $entry){
 $sql = "UPDATE voters SET vote_for_mayor=implode(',',$vote)";        
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
}

Comment: Each entry in `$_POST['vote']` and `$_POST['vote1']` should be a different row in the database, not imploded into a single row. I'm not sure how to do the query, since your form doesn't have anything corresponding to the `id` and `name` columns in the table.